# Access, DateSerial function causing inaccurate results (user inputs 2 digit month number)

Tags: vba, ms-access, user-input

The query shown below returns monthly results for the current year.  In order to create a new query that only returns a single month of results based on the month number that the user inputs, I modified the last 5 lines of code that involve the DateSerial function of the query.

The problem is that the new query has slightly different results for some months.  What is causing the results between the 2 queries to not match?  Other than the DateSerial function in the last 5 lines, the code has not been changed.

**Last 5 lines of code of new query**

```
 FROM (SELECT DateSerial(Year(Date()),[Enter 2 digit month number],1) AS month_start, 
    DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(Date()),[Enter 2 digit month number],31)) AS month_end 
    FROM SALES_RECEIPT 
    WHERE sale_date between DateSerial(Year(Date()), [Enter 2 digit month number], 1) and DateSerial(Year(Date()),[Enter 2 digit month number]+1, 0)
    GROUP BY Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date))  AS months;
```

**Query that returns monthly results for the current year:**

```
SELECT Format(DatePart("m",months.month_start),"00") & "/" & Year(months.month_start) AS [Month/Year],

(SELECT  Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end) AS [Gross Sales],

(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum((Nz(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0))*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end ) AS COGS,

(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) - Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM INVENTORY  INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between months.month_start and months.month_end) AS [Sales Margin],

(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) ,2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and SALES_RECEIPT.SALES_TAX_EXEMPT="No") AS [Taxable Sales],

(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) ,2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and SALES_RECEIPT.SALES_TAX_EXEMPT="Yes") AS [Tax Free Sales], 

(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) ,2) * .05
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and SALES_RECEIPT.SALES_TAX_EXEMPT="No") AS [Total Sales Tax],

(Select Round(Nz(Sum(Shipping_CHARGES.Shipping_COST),0),2)
FROM SHIPPING_CHARGES
WHERE SHIPPING_CHARGES.ENTRY_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end ) AS [Total Shipping Charges]

FROM (SELECT DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date), 1) AS month_start,
 DateAdd("d", -1,  DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date) + 1, 1)) AS month_end
 FROM SALES_RECEIPT
 WHERE sale_date between #1/1# And #12/31#
 GROUP BY Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date))  AS months;
```

Comment: Does your `sale_date` include **time** information? If yes, `2016-06-30 08:30` would be included in the original query, but not in the new one for month = 6.  `? (#2016-06-30 08:30# <= DateSerial(2016, 7, 0))` = False.

Comment: Also, if you really mean "month end", your expression doesn't return that because some months don't have 31 days. As you further deduct one day, you'll miss exactly the 31th of the months that have 31 days, and the last date of February will be a March date.

Comment: sale_date does not include time information.  I believe the problem is with the "month end".  The results for January is the same for both queries but the results for February don't match.  I checked the SALES_RECEIPT table and found that the sale entries for March 1st and 2nd are being added to the results for February (29 days in Feb. this year) which is causing the problem.  How could the DateSerial function of query in which the user inputs a month number be revised to eliminate this problem?

Comment: That surprises me, because the wrong formula is only used in the "display" section `AS month_end`. The WHERE clause has the correct formula `BETWEEN ... and DateSerial(Year(Date()),[month]+1, 0)`. -- But you may have better results by simply querying `WHERE Month(sale_date) = [Enter 2 digit month number]`.

Comment: If I change the WHERE clause to:  WHERE Month(sale_date) = [Enter 2 digit month number]  the query runs but it has all null results.

Comment: I haven't tried inserting it into your code, but in VBA the easiest way of determining if a date falls into the same month as another date is this: `DateDiff("M", Date1, Date2) = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a corrected version of the DateSerial function code that will return accurate results.

```
FROM (SELECT DateSerial(Year(date()), [Enter 2 digit month number], 1) AS month_start,
DateAdd("d", -1,  DateSerial(Year(date()), [Enter 2 digit month number] + 1, 1)) AS month_end 
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE sale_date between DateSerial(Year(Date()), [Enter 2 digit month number], 1) and DateSerial(Year(Date()), [Enter 2 digit month number]+1, 0) 
GROUP BY Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date))  AS months;
```